# How was the NullPointerException caused in this XML customview parsing error?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have all my code in an Asynch. More specifically, is it context which is causing this error? My logcat points to errors in FileCache,ImageLoader and my LazyAdapter. What went wrong exactly? How was the NullPointerException caused?

Logcat:

```
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): Process: com.example.clinicbooker, PID: 1074
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.example.functionalities.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:15)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.example.functionalities.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:33)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.example.clinicbooker.LazyAdapter.<init>(LazyAdapter.java:31)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(BookScreen.java:93)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(BookScreen.java:1)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-29 19:41:38.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

FileCache:

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

LazyAdapter:

```
 public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        public LazyAdapter(Context contextActivity , ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
           this.context=context;
            data=d;
            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
            View vi=convertView;

            inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_list_row,parent,false);

            resultp=data.get(position);


            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.menu_name); 
            TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.address); 
            TextView bookingDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.book_date); 
            TextView bookingTime = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.book_time);
            ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); 


            // Setting all values in listview
            title.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TITLE));
            description.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_ADDRESS));
            bookingDate.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_DATE));
            bookingTime.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TIME));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    resultp=data.get(position);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,SingleItemView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title",resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TITLE));
                    intent.putExtra("address",resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_ADDRESS));
                    intent.putExtra("date",resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_DATE));
                    intent.putExtra("time",resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TIME));
                    intent.putExtra("thumbnail",resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return vi;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: There are also errors pointing to method DownloadXML in class BookScreen, just thought i might lay that out here:

```
public class BookScreen extends Activity {

//array
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42241589/test.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_CLINIC = "clinic"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_main);
    new DownloadXML().execute();
}

private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void OnPreExectute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookScreen.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("List is loading");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        try {
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CLINIC);
            // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
                map.put(KEY_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TIME));
                map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ADDRESS));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(BookScreen.this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Close dialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This line in your `LazyAdapter` class assigns the field `context` to itself, leaving it null:

```
       this.context=context;
```

Likely you intended:

```
       this.context=contextActivity;
```

That improperly null value is passed as a constructor parameter to the other classes, eventually resulting in your null pointer exception.

After fixing this, additionally, in your `DownloadXML` class you have a method called `OnPreExectute` that should probably be `onPreExecute`.  Since this method initializes the `mProgressDialog`, and it's not being called, that field is not being initialized.

You really should learn how to use a debugger to locate these things.  This much I can guess at from your exceptions and code inspection, but

Comment: How silly of me, thank you for pointing that out! However I still get a NullPointerException and this time, it seems to be pointing at the last line of the onPostExecute, and also class DownLoadXML seems to have errors as well.